# How can I get a ZXing scanner in a section of a page?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, zxing

I'm currently using [this example source code](https://github.com/rajdeol/android-barcode-scanner-in-fragment/tree/master/app/src/main) to get a little bit familiar with [ZXing.](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) As of right now, the main screen looks like this:

[image: barcode main screen]

When you press the 'Scan' button, it opens up the scanner in fullscreen and locks the orientation to landscape. Now instead of the scanner opening up fullscreen, I want it to open up only in a portion of the main screen. In other words, the scanner should only be inside the red box:

[image]

I've slightly altered the layout of the main screen, so that the fragment appears below the button:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".HomeActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:id="@+id/tv_welcome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>
<TextView
    android:text="@string/blog_url"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_blog_url"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_scan_now"
    android:onClick="scanNow"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/btn_scan_now" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scan_format"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scan_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scan_fragment"
    android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the first image below, you'll see what I'm trying to achieve in my own app. The second is what I have so far. The black section is where I want the scanner to go. Currently all that is, is a linear layout reserved for the fragment:

[image]
[image]

But this is where I've come to a stand still. I'm not sure how I can prevent the scanner from going fullscreen and landscape as well as locking it down to a specific area of a page. Can anyone provide some guidance on how to achieve this?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: ZXing launches its own activity so you cant do what you want, use the android mobile vision api https://developers.google.com/vision/introduction

Comment: @tyczj Do you have any other recommendations for different scanner library I could use? EDIT: Oh, nevermind, I misread your comment, I'll look into the API.